# Solr Jetty 8 restrict access by IP

Tags: java, solr, ip, jetty

I was wondering whats the best way to limit access to a solr instance running on top of jetty 8.1 based on IP address. I could do it on the firewall level, but I would rather have it on the web server level. I saw many references to articles which point the use of HtAccess file but apparently in newer jetty versions > 6, this component is no longer part of jetty. So I would imagine its fairly simple to restrict access to only a few select IPs but I cant find any documentation on that topic anywhere. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out the IPAccessHandler in jetty 8, it is in the jetty-server package.

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-
server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/IPAccessHandler.java?h=jetty-8

[edit] the docs page

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/ipaccess-handler.html

Comment: Link to [IPAccessHandler javadoc](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/IPAccessHandler.html) and [the test case for it](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-server/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/IPAccessHandlerTest.java).